# Rigorous Formalization of the Data/Computation Duality?

Tags: complexity-theory

It seems to be a matter of computer science lore that data and computation (or data and *process*, whatever you want to call it) are in some vague sense duals of each other: data is generated by computation but also guides future computation, and so the two are, vaguely, two sides of the same coin. This duality is more apparent in programming languages like Lisp which purposefully blur the line between the two.

I'm wondering whether this notion of duality has been studied in complexity theory in a rigorous setting. For instance, are there any computational models in which this duality arises naturally out of some deeper duality intrinsic to the model? For instance--and this is wishful thinking bordering on the nonsensical--if, say, we equated *data* with the states of a DFA and *process* with the DFA's transition function, and then the graph-dual of the DFA would yield another DFA related to the original in some meaningful way, *then* the data/computation duality would emerge naturally from the underlying model.

That sort of thing. Any pointers to research in the area (or even just keywords) are appreciated.

Comment: The thing about dual graphs of DFAs is guaranteed not to work; the dual of a graph is only defined relative to a planar embedding of it. Most DFAs will not be planar, and even those which are don't have a *canonical* planar embedding.

Comment: The only kind of dual which comes to my mind in this context is the duality in function application between the function and the input; if you think of function application as an operation with two inputs (a function and a value from its domain), then it is possible to view it such that e.g. the number 3 is like a "function" which maps (x -> x + 1) to the number 4, it maps (x -> x^2) to the number 9, and maps (x -> 2x + 5) to the number 11.